# Capturing STDOUT of a process in C#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, process, stdout

I use in my software 2 different processes. In both cases I read the process output and a give the user some indication about it.

```
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();

si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
si.UseShellExecute = false;
si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.RedirectStandardError = true;
si.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

si.FileName = "proc.exe";
si.Arguments = "some args";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = si;
p.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
p.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

p.Start();
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.BeginErrorReadLine();

p.WaitForExit();
```

In the first case it works perfect! 
but in the other case the process is doing its job but only the termination events are being fired.
When running it with

```
si.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
```

I see that there is an output for this process .

What can be the problem? Why the output events aren't being fired?

Comment: You are right.. I meant Normal - edited

Answer (score 1):

So if one process works, but the other doesn't, are you sure the other process is actually writing to stdout?

A quick test can confirm. Run it from the command line with the following syntax;

myprocess.exe > output.txt

If output.txt is empty, then it is not writing to stdout and your program is working fine.